# Memory leak issues in Fragment

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-profiler

I have implemented MVP pattern in my app. And I'm using WeakReferences to store View's reference in my Presenter. But still my fragments are not being claimed by GC upon destroying. Below is the screenshot of problem. Any idea what is causing this and how to remove this issue?

[image: Screenshot of Android Profiler]

Below is the code for my Presenter:

```
public class ProductDetailPresenter implements ProductDetailContract.Presenter {

private final WeakReference<ProductDetailContract.View> view;
private CategoriesDataSource repo;

public ProductDetailPresenter(ProductDetailContract.View view, CategoriesDataSource repo) {
    this.view = new WeakReference<>(view);
    this.repo = repo;
    view.setPresenter(this);
}

@Override
public void start() {

}

@Override
public void submitRating(final Product product, final float mRating) {
    final ProductDetailContract.View view =ProductDetailPresenter.this.view.get();

    if (view != null) {
        repo.submitRating(product.getId(), mRating, true, new CategoriesDataSource.SubmitRatingCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingSubmitted() {

                product.setRating(mRating);
                product.setRated(true);
                product.setUpdatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                repo.updateProductInDB(product);

                if (!view.isActive()) return;

                view.onRatingSubmitted(true, mRating);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                if (!view.isActive()) return;

                view.onRatingSubmitted(false, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onRateKarenClicked() {
    ProductDetailContract.View view = this.view.get();
    if (view != null) {
        view.openDialog();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAbhiKhareediyeClicked(Product product) {

    EventBus.getDefault().post(
            new ProductDetailContract.ContractEventMessages(
                    ProductDetailContract.ContractEventMessages.EVENT_START_QUANTITY_SCREEN, product));

}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure if this is the reason, but you are using weak references in a wrong way. You take your weak reference, acquire a strong reference if the view exists, and then you make `submitRating` call while having a strong reference to your view. Instead, you should only get a strong reference when the request finishes, this is the whole purpose of using a weak reference. Try fixing it and see if that was the reason of the leak.

Comment: No this is not an issue. I have just verified.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
    @Override
    public void submitRating(final Product product, final float mRating) {
       final ProductDetailContract.View view =ProductDetailPresenter.this.view.get(); <-- this is bad
```

you have a final object that is being passed to the repo. Delete the whole line. You don't need it. Use in the view.get() inside the onRatingSubmitted and onError